# SQLITE_TRANSIENT undefined in Swift

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift

I'm using xcode 6 and I've imported `libsqlite3.dylib` and `libsqlite3.0.dylib`. I've also added the `Bridging-Header.h` file witch imports sqlite3.h

I can open SQLite database and do simple operations like insert select...

With 
`if (sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, Name.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)`

I have an error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'SQLITE_TRANSIENT'`

What show I do? I'm new in Swift, it's my first question on Stack, pls somebody help me!

Comment: show some code like how you import  sqlite3.h?

Comment: in my Bridging-Header.h I add #import <sqlite3.h> . I think it's because in my sqlite3.h it doesn't define SQLITE_TRANSIENT and SQLITE_STATIC because I can use other constants like SQLITE_OK, SQLITE_DONE.

Comment: yeah error simply says that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The definitions

```
#define SQLITE_STATIC      ((sqlite3_destructor_type)0)
#define SQLITE_TRANSIENT   ((sqlite3_destructor_type)-1)
```

from `<sqlite3.h>` are not imported to Swift, probably due to the "unsafe" pointer casting.

A possible Swift definition is shown in the 
[SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) project, in 
[Statement.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/SQLite/Statement.swift):

```
let SQLITE_STATIC = sqlite3_destructor_type(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: 0))
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = sqlite3_destructor_type(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: -1))
```

For **Swift 2** you will need

```
let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

(taken from ["Helpers.swift"](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/swift-2/Source/Helpers.swift) from the Swift 2 branch of the SQLite.swift project).

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

Comment: How about swift4?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey: If it works in Swift 3 and Swift 4.2 then I strongly assume that it works in Swift 4 as well. Do you have problems with it?

Comment: @MartinR: My mistake...it is working fine! Upvote for answer.

Comment: I know this is Swift, and not Objective-C, but should you add a three-letter prefix to each constant name, eg, changing them to `WOZ_SQLITE_STATIC` & `WOZ_SQLITE_TRANSIENT`, to avoid naming collisions (eg, in case Apple fixes this issue in a future release)?

Comment: @ma11hew28: I do not think that is necessary because of the Swift modules. If SQLITE_STATIC is eventually imported from libsqlite then its fully qualified name would be SQLite3.SQLITE_STATIC, and your own constant would be YourAppModule.SQLITE_STATIC.

Comment: @MartinR, OK, thanks. That makes sense. But if I use the unqualified names in my code, then I think my local declarations would override those (if imported in the future) of SQLite3. So ideally maybe we'd want to wrap each definition inside `#ifndef SQLITE_STATIC` and `#ifndef SQLITE_TRANSIENT`, respectively? But I don't know how to do that in Swift. Anyway, it's probably fine because the developers of SQLite probably won't change the definitions of these constants.