# sqlite for swift is unstable

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift

I've set up swift project to use sqlite.  sometimes, when inserting it doesn't actually insert the correct (or all) the values.  I know because I restart the app, and when I come back in the entries are either randomly wrong (with stuff not inserted) or nil.  but sometimes correct.

here is where I set it, and yes the data is correct in the values before inserting.

```
let update = "INSERT INTO ToDoItem (itemName, completed, goalDate) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
var statement: COpaquePointer = nil
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    let itemName = item.itemName as String
    let completed = item.completed == true ? 1 : 0

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, itemName, -1, nil)
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, Int32(completed))

    if let goalDate = item.goalDate?.toString() {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, goalDate, -1, nil)
    } else {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, "", -1, nil)
    }

    //println("inserting \(itemName), \(completed) and \(item.goalDate?.toString())")
    //println("")
}

if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
    println("error updateing table")
    sqlite3_close(database)
    return
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement)

sqlite3_close(database)
```

you can see the commented out println in the middle, if that is not commented out, then the itemName sometimes gets part of that string.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found the way to resolve this problem.

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, itemName, -1, nil) --> itemName should be UTF8 String
```

You should convert `itemName` as `NSString` and use `UTF8String` to convert your string to `UTF8`. Right code is the same here

```swift
let itemName = item.itemName as NSString
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, itemName.UTF8String, -1, nil)
```

Good luck.

Comment: You also have to use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` for the last parameter to `sqlite3_bind_text`.

Comment: SQLITE_TRANSIENT is not available swift 3? can you please advise.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I found this answer that covers manually defining SQLITE_TRANSIENT in Swift 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884081/470339

Answer (score 13):

In swift SQLite doesn't have `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` and `SQLITE_STATIC` defined, so we need to explicitly define it.

**swift 3 & 4**

**Define following property of SQLITE**

```
let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

**SQL function**
Add `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` instead of `nil` as last parameter while binding text `sqlite3_bind_text`.

```
let update = "INSERT INTO ToDoItem (itemName, completed, goalDate) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
var statement: OpaquePointer = nil
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    let itemName = item.itemName as String
    let completed = item.completed == true ? 1 : 0

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, itemName, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, Int32(completed))

    if let goalDate = item.goalDate?.toString() {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, goalDate, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
    } else {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, "", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
    }

    //println("inserting \(itemName), \(completed) and \(item.goalDate?.toString())")
    //println("")
}

if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
    println("error updateing table")
    sqlite3_close(database)
    return
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement)

sqlite3_close(database)
```

> Referenced from [SQLITE_TRANSIENT undefined in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883131/sqlite-transient-undefined-in-swift)

Answer (score -1):

This behavior actually does conform to the specification and the bug is in your code.

The source of your problem is in the swift `String` you are passing to `sqlite3_bind_text`. `sqlite3_bind_text` accepts the text as a `const char*` which is bridged as `UnsafePointer<CChar>` in Swift. The behavior when passing a Swift `String` to a function that accepts `UnsafePointer<CChar>` is documented in the "Constant Pointers" section of the [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html). It says:

> The string will automatically be converted to UTF8 in a buffer, and a pointer to that buffer is passed to the function.

Which is probably what you want to have happen.

**BUT** it also says:

> The pointer passed to the function is guaranteed to be valid only for the duration of the function call. Don’t try to persist the pointer and access it after the function has returned.

This is the source of your bug. `sqlite3_bind_text()` does in fact persist the pointer in the prepared statement possibly until `sqlite3_finalize()` is called so that it can use it in future `sqlite3_step()` calls.

Another answer suggested using `NSString.UTF8String`. This has a lifetime that is a little longer and seems like it should be enough. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String) says:

> This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you use this property.

"memory context" here seems vague. I'm not sure if it means the current function, or until the current autoreleasepool is drained, or something else. If it is one of the first two, you are safe. If not, well I would say you are still safe because it seems like `NSString.UTF8String` has been used in situations like these for a long time without issues..