# Sqlite3 inserting BLOBs instead of text

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have an ACTIVITY entity that has been created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVITY (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, TYPE TEXT, DESCRIPTION TEXT);
```

I'm trying to save an Activity object in the Sqlite3 database this way:

```
func save(database:COpaquePointer) -> Int
{
    let id = getMaxActivityId(database) + 1;
    let insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ACTIVITY (TYPE, ID, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?,?,?);"
    var statement:COpaquePointer = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertQuery, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1,type, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, Int32(id))

        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, description ?? "", -1, nil)
    }

    if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE
    {
        let e = NSException(name: "Failed to insert Activity", reason: nil, userInfo: nil)
        e.raise()
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    return id
}
```

The values are:

```
activity.type = "Walking"
activity.id = 12
activity.description = Optional(nil)
```

When retrieving the data it seems to be inconsistent, and if I try downloading the app container and checking the database, I can see that in the type field, a BLOB type is being inserted instead of a string:

[image]
[image]

If I try changing the type to "text" it shows this message:

[image]

The app I'm using is "Sqlite Browser" 3.8.0 for Os X.

Comment: The order of the keys in the INSERT statement is different from the order of the keys in the CREATE TABLE statement, but I don't assume that that matters. – It looks as if the first 4 records were created correctly, did you change something in between?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the DESCRIPTION field was created afterwards (ALTER TABLE ACTIVITY ADD COLUMN DESCRIPTION TEXT).

Comment: Strange fact: if I don't bind the 3rd value (description), the type field gets inserted correctly.

Comment: What exact type has the description property?

Comment: It's type is TEXT.

Comment: I meant the type of the Swift property `activity.description`

Comment: It's a String (not optional). I tried saving it as a UTF8String and there are no problems now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Later on I discovered that I should to save the string as UTF8, and not just a plain Swift string, otherwise I may get unwanted behaviours:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, Int32(id))
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2,(type as NSString).UTF8String, -1, nil)

let desc = (description ?? "") as NSString
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, desc.UTF8String, -1, nil)
```

I've found the solution [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142226/sqlite-for-swift-is-unstable).

Comment: BTW, you should use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` for that last parameter to `sqlite3_bind_text`.