# Saving database changes into .db file with SQLite (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

In my Project I am opening an already existing database from a `.db` with `sqlite3_open`. This file was created with the command-line tool `sqlite3`. I am updating some rows in a table, which works fine, but those updates are only made in the temporary instance of the database. How can I also update my `.db` file for future runs of my project to work with updated data?

Somebody asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593741/saving-sqlite-database-with-swift) how to save a SQLite database in Swift. But the answer seems to me somehow unsatisfying, because the file should be written in the same format as created by `sqlite3`, so that it can be opened again via `sqlite3_open`.

Is there maybe even a function presented by SQLite? I couldn't find anything for that...

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary instance"? Are you not doing what all apps do and that is to copy the bundled database file from the resource bundle to the Documents folder or other appropriate sandbox folder on first run and then using using that copy when opening and using the database?

Comment: I simply dragged the database file into my project in Xcode. I selected 'Create groups' and added it to the target. Programmatically I don't do anything special. I just open the file and update some rows as mentioned.

Comment: If you were running on a real device your app would work at all since the app's bundle is read-only.

Comment: you mean wouldn't?

Comment: Place the database file in the users Document directory or some similar and open it from there.

Comment: Oops. Yes, I meant would *not*.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson but how can I access the file on an Iphone, when i put it in my Document directory?

Comment: I mean the Document folder on your iPhone, the one in the sandbox, `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`. Or any other place in the users home directory

Comment: How can I place the database file in that directory on my Iphone/Emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the contents of the bundle. So you will want to copy the file to some a directory where it can be modified. Historically we might have advised using “documents” folder for this. But nowadays we use the “application support directory”. See [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/204/).

Anyway, the basic idea is:

- include the original database in the bundle (by adding it to your app’s target, if you haven’t already);

  [image]
- try to open the database (with `SQLITE_READWRITE` option but not the `SQLITE_CREATE` option ... we don’t want it creating a blank database if it doesn’t find it) in the application support directory; and
- if that fails (because the file is not found), copy the database from the bundle to the application support directory and try again

Thus, perhaps something like:

```
var db: OpaquePointer?

enum DatabaseError: Error {
    case bundleDatabaseNotFound
    case sqliteError(Int32, String?)
}

func openDatabase() throws {
    let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("database.db")

    // try opening database and just return if it succeeded

    if sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        return
    }

    // if it failed, clean up before trying again ...

    sqlite3_close(db)
    db = nil

    // then copy database from bundle ...

    guard let bundlePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "database", withExtension: "db") else {
        throw DatabaseError.bundleDatabaseNotFound
    }
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundlePath, to: fileURL)

    // and try again

    let rc = sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil)

    if rc == SQLITE_OK { return }

    // and if it still failed, again, clean up, and then throw error

    let errorMessage = sqlite3_errmsg(db)
        .flatMap { String(cString: $0) }

    sqlite3_close(db)
    db = nil

    throw DatabaseError.sqliteError(rc, errorMessage)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed