# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'sqlite3_destructor_type'

Tags: swift, swift2

So far the [answer from Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883131/cant-find-sqlite-transient-in-xcode-6-swift/26884081#26884081) has worked perfectly. But starting with Swift2 it now raises the error

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'sqlite3_destructor_type' with an argument list of type '(COpaquePointer)'

in those lines:

```
private let SQLITE_STATIC = sqlite3_destructor_type(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: 0))      // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884081/1271826
private let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = sqlite3_destructor_type(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: -1))
```

Comment: This is discussed in https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/133 (note that the code from my answer also came from that project). I have no idea if the proposed solution works.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the github post provided courtesy of @MartinR the answer is

```
internal let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
internal let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```