# SQLite insert into Swift causing loop Swift 3.1

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to insert an array into SQLite with Swift 3.1

When I use the "if" statement, a single insert is achieved without issues.  However, I need this to insert an Array, so I need to use the "while" statement.  However, this is causing the insert statement to run in a loop.

```
func insertDiveGear() {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    let names = itemDataArray

    let update = "INSERT INTO DiveGearForDive (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);"

    while sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.dlDatabase.database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

        for (_ , name) in names.enumerated() {

            let diveNumber = Int32(diveNumber)

            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, diveNumber)
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, name, -1, nil)

            if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: It is unclear to me why you need that while-loop. `sqlite3_prepare_v2` should be called once, and `sqlite3_bind_XXX`/`sqlite3_step` in a loop for all items to insert.

Comment: ... calling `sqlite3_reset` each time, too.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it later and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't exit `while` loop because the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will not fail. But no `while` loop is needed. You can do something like:

```
func insertDiveGear() {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    let names = itemDataArray

    let update = "INSERT INTO DiveGearForDive (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);"

    for (diveNumber, name) in names.enumerated() {
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(dlDatabase.database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, Int32(diveNumber))
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, name, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

            if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                print("Successfully inserted row.")
            } else {
                print("Could not insert row.")
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement)
        }
    }
}
```

Or, even more efficient, prepare the statement only once, and then loop through binding, stepping, and then resetting:

```
func insertDiveGear() {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    let names = itemDataArray

    let update = "INSERT INTO DiveGearForDive (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);"

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(dlDatabase.database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(dlDatabase.database))
        print("failure preparing: \(errmsg)")
        return
    }

    for (diveNumber, name) in names.enumerated() {
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, Int32(diveNumber))
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, name, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not insert row.")
        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement)
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement)
}
```

I didn't know what to make of that `let diveNumber = Int32(diveNumber)` line (where is `diveNumber` defined; using the same name?; etc.), so adjust that as you see fit, but the main question is why the loop didn't exit, and it's because `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will always return `SQLITE_OK` if the SQL is well formed.

Also note, I used `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` constant (see [Cannot invoke initializer for type 'sqlite3_destructor_type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760353/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-sqlite3-destructor-type)) in conjunction with [`sqlite3_bind_text`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to ensure that SQLite creates its own copy of the string that it received, which is prudent when dealing with Swift strings.