# How to add a relation in a SQLite insert?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I would like to know, as for adding Int and Text, how to add a relation in an insert?

I can't find sqlite3_bind_relationship or foreign key.

```
let insertRequest = "INSERT INTO Entity (Id, Name, OtherClass) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"

func insert(class: Class, otherClass : OtherClass) {
    var insertQuery: OpaquePointer?

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(openDatabase(), insertRequest, -1, &insertQuery, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        let id: Int32 = class.id
        let name: String = class.name
        let otherClass : OtherClass = otherClass

        sqlite3_bind_int(insertQuery, 1, id)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertQuery, 2, descriptionPrevent, -1, nil)
            // What sqlite3_bin_ for other class ?
        sqlite3_bind_??
           
            
        if sqlite3_step(insertQuery) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row prevent.")
        } else {
            print("Could not insert row.")
        }
    } else {
        print("\nINSERT statement is not prepared.")
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertQuery)
}
```

I use CoreData to make my entities and I use relationship to link them.

Comment: You use the primary key of the other table. Have you added a foreign key to the `Entity` table?

Comment: I use relationship in coreData

Comment: I use CoreData to make my entities and I use relationship to link them

Comment: If you are using CoreData, then you really should be using CoreData to insert items in your persistent store, not going in the backdoor with SQLite. You can easily mess up the database integrity by inserting values yourself (if you ever plan on accessing them from CoreData, at least; e.g. If you insert a row, are you also updating the `Z_PRIMARYKEY` table?). Then, again, your column names don't look like standard CoreData database column names, so this doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: I can only agree, delete that code and use Core Data to instead.

Comment: Unrelated, the `sqlite3_finalize` should go into the `if` clause. The docs are inconsistent on this matter (one reference says finalizing with `NULL` statement is no-op, another says that statement must not be `NULL`), but, either way, one doesn’t “finalize” a failed “prepare”. (This is, admittedly, unlike `sqlite3_open_xxx` which must be “closed” whether it succeeded or not.) Also, if it failed, `sqlite3_errmsg` is invaluable for diagnosing issues.

Comment: Also unrelated, I generally avoid using `nil` for the last parameter of `sqlite3_bind_text`. I would recommend using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31425154/1271826) as we never want to make assumptions about the lifespans and memory addresses that Swift uses behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> I use CoreData to make my entities and I use relationship to link them

If you are using CoreData, then you really should be using CoreData to insert items in your persistent store, not going in the backdoor with SQLite. You can easily mess up the database integrity by inserting values yourself.

Then, again, your column names don't look like standard CoreData database. For example, if I look at a simple CoreData database that I just created for “books” and “authors”, its schema looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ZAUTHOR ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZNAME VARCHAR );
CREATE TABLE ZBOOK ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZAUTHOR INTEGER, ZTITLE VARCHAR );
CREATE INDEX ZBOOK_ZAUTHOR_INDEX ON ZBOOK (ZAUTHOR);
CREATE TABLE Z_PRIMARYKEY (Z_ENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_NAME VARCHAR, Z_SUPER INTEGER, Z_MAX INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_UUID VARCHAR(255), Z_PLIST BLOB);
CREATE TABLE Z_MODELCACHE (Z_CONTENT BLOB);
```

Whereas, if I were to create this in SQLite myself, it might look like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE author (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, title TEXT NOT NULL, author_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES author(id));
CREATE INDEX idx_book_author ON book(author_id);
```

Let's consider the latter example, and assume that the database looks like:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM author;
id  name
--  -------------------
1   William Faulkner
2   William Shakespeare

sqlite> SELECT * FROM book;
id  title                   author_id
--  ----------------------  ---------
1   The Sound and the Fury  1
2   As I Lay Dying          1
3   Henry V                 2
```

If I were to insert a new book for Shakespeare, it would be:

```sql
INSERT INTO book (title, author_id) VALUES('Romeo and Juliet', 2);
```

If doing this programmatically, that `author_id` parameter would be `sqlite3_bind_int` of the value `2`, which is the primary key for Shakespeare in the `author` table. And I personally would let SQLite generate the `id` for this row, which can be fetched with [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).

Now, that is an over-simplified example. Sometimes (such as this books-authors example), you would have a many-to-many relationship (where a book could have multiple authors and each author might have multiple books for which they were the author). In that case, the `book` table might not have an `author_id` column, but rather there might be a separate cross-reference table, e.g., `book_author` which contained these `id` cross references for books and authors. But, again, these `id` columns would be a type that matches that of the foreign key types (commonly integers in SQLite databases). The point is merely that how and where these foreign references might be will vary based upon the type of entity-relationships.

But, again, if this is really CoreData database, this is all moot, as I would advise against ever inserting rows (or do any direct interaction) via SQLite. Use CoreData. E.g., going back to the one-to-many example captured in the CoreData schema at the top of this answer, to add a `Book` with a reference to an `Author`, I might do the following:

```swift
private func addBook(_ title: String, for author: Author) throws {
    let book = Book(context: viewContext)
    book.title = title
    book.author = author

    try viewContext.save()
}
```

Behind the scenes, CoreData is really doing something very close to the `id` foreign key pattern outlined above, but it takes care of all of those details for us and we would avoid circumventing CoreData. We let CoreData do this for us.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for you anwser !

But i have an other question, I have to insert data when I download the app, I was advised to insert them directly into the database with SQLite.

You said "you can easily mess up the database integrity by inserting values yourself." can you tell me more about why this is a bad practice please ? :)

Comment: With no offense to whomever offered that advice, that’s just bad counsel. Apple explicitly warns us against this practice: “… nor should you manipulate an existing Core Data SQLite store using native SQLite API.” The internal structure of a CoreData database is an implementation detail which is subject to change without warning. The Z_PRIMARYKEY and/or CloudKit are likely issues. Besides, inserting via CoreData is just easier. Why not use CoreData?

Comment: But, hey, if you prefer to go “old school” and use SQLite, then just do that (probably use one of the many SQLite wrapper libraries that simplify that process), but you’d then just want abandon CoreData, entirely. Many of us have written SQLite-based apps without CoreData and it works great. It gives you the ultimate control. But you lose out on the CoreData benefits, too. But, in short, if you are going to use CoreData, you are well advised to not manipulate the SQLite store directly.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer! So I will use core Data, I modified what I had done to follow your example, thanks again !! :D

Comment: I have an other question, can i, with Core Data, get the primaty key of an entity ??

Comment: We are abstracted away from these details. For example, in the CoreData code snippet in my answer, even though behind the scenes `Book` table has a column with the author integer identifier value, but in code, we never reference these identifiers. When creating a book, I don't reference the author identifier, but rather just the `Author` instance. It took care of populating the foreign key integer value for us. Now, if you need a reference to this object that you can use later, you might use the `urlRepresentation()` of the object’s `objectID`, but that’s a bit of an edge case, IMHO.