# Swift 2 @convention use error

Tags: swift, swift2, convention

I have a problem with Swift 2, I'm not able to convert this part of my code:

```
let intTran = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(bitPattern: -1)
let tranPointer = COpaquePointer(intTran)
let transient = CFunctionPointer<((UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void)>(tranPointer)
```

I receive this error:

> 'CFunctionPointer' is unavailable: use a function type '@convention(c) (T) -> U'

I am trying to change it for this way:

```
let intTran = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(bitPattern: -1)
let tranPointer = COpaquePointer(intTran)
typealias transient2 = @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void
```

But I am not able to use transient2 and I am not sure why.

Than you

Comment: Have a look at [SQLITE_TRANSIENT undefined in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883131/sqlite-transient-undefined-in-swift) which has been updated for Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with your code inside a Swift playground and noticed that this piece of code (your substitution to the original one) fails due to the bitPattern when it's set to -1 (notice that I've been getting a runtime exception - not a compiler error). When I replaced it with something appropriate (e.g. with 1, as bitPattern must represent a valid address inside you virtual address space and, as implied, must be a non-negative integer) it worked out. I managed to make it up and running with the following code:

```
import Foundation

let intTran = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 1)
let tranPointer = COpaquePointer(intTran)

typealias transient2 = @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void

let abc: transient2? = nil
```

Good luck, hope this solves your problem.