# sqliteDB in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I was reading the sqlite in swift. These there line are not clear to me what does these mean ?

```
var errMsg:  UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>? = nil
internal let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, to:sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
internal let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1,  to:sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883131/sqlite-transient-undefined-in-swift.

Comment: Hello. There's a lot of topics in your question, and it's uneasy to give any hint until you say what you are not comfortable with. Is it [UnsafeMutablePointer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer)? [unsafeBitCast](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641250-unsafebitcast)? [sqlite3_destructor_type, SQLITE_STATIC, SQLITE_TRANSIENT](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_static.html)? There is chance that after reading those documentation links you may have a more precise question to ask.

Comment: A general hint, though: this is the kind of code that you may happen to read when Swift has to interact with C. SQLite is written in C.

Comment: Thank you @GwendalRoué . declartion of errMsg is not clear to me.

Comment: Well, `errMsg` is a pointer to a pointer to a byte. A `char**` in C. It's most certainly a pointer to a string, and I guess `errMsg` is set by some function that has uses it as an argument, and that you didn't show. *Read* the documentation of this function. It will make you understand the *purpose* of `errMsg`. If you don't know what a pointer is in C, then get a *crash course*. Again, the topic is too *wide*, and your question much too *imprecise*. It's impossible to guess what are your *current skills*, and to provide any *adapted answer*.