# Swift 4 + SQLite when inserting

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am using the "raw" C functions to access my SQLite database and getting 2 problems with date and text fields, my code, considere that all is already working:

```
let queryString = "INSERT INTO LOG (field1, field2, field3, field4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);" 
if sqlitePrepare(database: &db, query: queryString, statement: &insertStatement) == SQLITE_OK {
    sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 1, intVar)
    sqlite3_bind_double(insertStatement, 2, Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, strVar1, -1, nil)
    sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, strVar2, -1, nil)
    if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) != SQLITE_DONE {
          let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
         print("failure insert: \(errmsg)")
     }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
}
```

Issue #1 is how to populate the Date field as a valid SQLite timestamp?
Issue #2 and more important, the values that are updated into the table with the string fields (field3/field4) are wrong. Only the last value is used to fill both (strVar1/strVar2), so if strVar1 = "A" and strVar2 = "B", both field3 and field4 are saved as "B", value of strVar2.
This is very weird because all examples I found have no difference here.

Comment: You need to show where the values for `strVar1` and `strVar2` come from.

Comment: The last parameter to [bind_text](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) is wrong.

Comment: Well, strVar1 and strVar2 can (are) declared as Swift String type:
var strVar1: String = "some text....", to test here I just put such line before the Prepare

Comment: @CL.every single example I saw uses nil as the last parameter. As not using sqlite3_bind_text64() I guess I should not mess with encoding (the sixth argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***#1 is how to populate the Date field as a valid SQLite timestamp?***

SQLite3 has no DATETIME type nor TIMESTAMP type. So, you need to store a timestamp as a TEXT or NUMERIC.

When you choose NUMERIC, you should better use UNIX epoch time.

```
sqlite3_bind_double(insertStatement, 2, Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
```

***#2***

Swift allocates a temporary region to store UTF-8 representation when passing a String to a parameter of type `UnsafePointer<Int8>`. And the region is released immediately after the call to the function, and may be reused.

Try this:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, strdup(strVar1), -1, free)
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, strdup(strVar2), -1, free)
```

`strdup` allocates a stable region which is available until `free`d.

Or (thanks to rmaddy and [Martin R "SQLITE_TRANSIENT undefined in Swift"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26883131/6541007)), you can use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`.

Define somewhere in your code:

```
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

And use it:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, strVar1, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 4, strVar2, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
```

Comment: It's simpler to use `sqlite3_bind_text` as: `sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, strVar1, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)`.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to to fix it to too by casting as NSString and set utf8String, but you solution is more direct using strdup().